# Websocket code to be improved

Tags: java, spring, websocket

This is the plain websocket code that connects with mobile app. Once we send a REST request from another service say B to our service A we send a websocket payload over the response. This runs in kubernetes pod. Could you suggest how to improve this?

```
@Component
public class WebSocketServer {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class);
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static final Map<String, Session> sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    @Value("${ws.session.id}")
    private String sessionId;

    public void pushEvent(String sessionVariable, Object message) throws IOException {
        logger.info("Inside pushEvent..");
        String sessionHeaderData = null;
        boolean matchFound = false;
        for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : SocketHandler.getSessions()) {
            sessionHeaderData= webSocketSession.getHandshakeHeaders().getFirst(sessionId);
            if (sessionHeaderData != null && sessionHeaderData.equals(sessionVariable)) {
                String payload = new Gson().toJson(message);
                logger.info("Payload:: {}", payload);
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(new TextMessage(payload));
                logger.info("Message sent successfully for session with ID:: {}", webSocketSession.getId());
                matchFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!matchFound) {
            logger.error("No matching websocket session found ! for {}", sessionVariable);
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
@Service
public class WSWelcomeServiceImpl implements WSWelcomeService {
    
    private static final String TOTAL_ITEMS_QUANTITY = "Total items quantity";


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WSWelcomeServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketServer webSocketServer;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Void> sendEvent(String accountNo, Event event) {
        Event pushEvent=null;
        logger.info("Triggering websocket  {} {} ", easeAccountNo, event);
        String eventCode = event.getEventTypeCode().toString();
        logger.info("Event received:: {}",eventCode);
        logger.info("Event Value Received:: {}", EventTypeCodeEnum.ITEM_QUANTITY.getValue());
        if(eventCode.equalsIgnoreCase(EventTypeCodeEnum.ITEM_QUANTITY.getValue())) {
            logger.info("Item Quantity Event received");
            pushEvent = pushItemQtyEvent(easeAccountNo, event);
        }else {
            pushEvent=event;
        }
        try {
            logger.info("Evenet Payload:: {}",new Gson().toJson(pushEvent));
            webSocketServer.pushEvent(String.valueOf(accountNo), pushEvent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception occured during ws connection {}", e);
            throw new ClientCommunicationException(ErrorCodes.CLIENT_COMMUNICATION_ERROR.getErrorCode(),
                    ErrorCodes.CLIENT_COMMUNICATION_ERROR.getDescription());
        }
        logger.info("Exiting websocket controller");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.valueOf(200));
    }
    private Event pushItemQtyEvent(String accountNo, Event event) {
        logger.info("Inside pushItemQtyEvent..");
        Event itemQtyEvent = new Event();
        itemQtyEvent.setAccountNo(accountNo.toString());
        itemQtyEvent.setEventTypeCode(EventTypeCodeEnum.ITEM_QUANTITY);
        itemQtyEvent.setEventTypeDesc(TOTAL_ITEMS_QUANTITY);
        QtyEvent qtyEvent = new QtyEvent();
        logger.info("Data Received:: {}", event.getData());
        logger.info("Item Quantity:: {}",event.getEventTypeDesc());
        qtyEvent.setTotalItemQty(BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(event.getEventTypeDesc())));
        itemQtyEvent.setData(qtyEvent);
        return itemQtyEvent;
    }

}
```